# Can we pass where condition in insert into statement if not what is the solution in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to create user on button click for a reseller. This is my Scenario:
I have a reseller module where reseller can request for users. This request has id, num_of_users_required and the date of request, which is stored in table called user_requests. Now these requests are fetched in Admin Module. Like this:

[image: Requests]

Now If admin clicks yes then i want to creates users for that reseller [eg: 1Linux-97-500-1 here is reseller so want to create users for that reseller]

Now Each user is identified by a unique field called key. in this field i insert the unique key of reseller. So Each user is mapped to its reseller by the reseller key wo we know which user belongs to which reseller.

Now on my View i have :

```
<tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td><?php echo  $user->id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo  $user->user_requested; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo  $user->key; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo  $user->date_requested; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo anchor('admin/reseller/create_user/' . $user->id,'Yes'); ?></td>
    <td><a href="reseller/change_status" class="btn btn-danger">No&nbsp<?php echo'<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>';?></a></td>
    <td><a href="" class="btn btn-success"><?php echo  $user->status; ?></td>&nbsp</a></td>
 </tr>
```

This generates the view as per above image now if i click yes then this is my method of creating users.:

```
      public function create_user($id)
      {


            $this->load->model('more_m');

            $rajan =$this->more_m->get(array('user_requested',$id));

            $request=$rajan->user_requested;        

            $this->load->model('reseller_m');

            $query=$this->db->select('key');

            $query=$this->db->get('reseller');

            if($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                $row = $query->row_array();

                $key= $row['key'];
            }


                    for($i=1; $i<=$request;$i++)
                        {

                        $mydata=array('key'=>$key);


                        $this->db->insert('users',$mydata);
                        echo $this->db->last_query();

                        die();

                        }


            $this->load->model('more_m');

            $this->db->set('status', "'approved'",FALSE);

            $this->db->where('id',$id);

            $this->db->update('user_request');


            redirect('admin/new_user');

      }
```

The for loop inserts into user table where key is the key of the reseller.

This is my query generated :

**INSERT INTO `users` (`key`) VALUES ('Rajan-92-1-100-1')**

So the code works fine for first request but if i click on 2nd request and approve that then it inserts user for 1st reseller. So i guess there should be id associated here.

I hope You understood my problem.

**The table Structure :**

1) Reseller Table

[image: Reseller Table]

2) Users Table

[image: Users table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing a silly mistake in fetching the Reseller's key.

```
      public function create_user($id)
      {


            $this->load->model('more_m');

            $rajan =$this->more_m->get(array('user_requested',$id));
            $request=$rajan->user_requested;        


            $this->load->model('reseller_m');

            $query=$this->db->select('key');
            $query=$this->db->where('id',$id);
            $query=$this->db->get('reseller');


            if($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
                   {
                    $row = $query->row_array();
                    $key= $row['key'];
                   }

            }

                    for($i=1; $i<=$request;$i++)
                        {

                        $userdata=array('key'=>$key);
                        $this->db->where('id',$id); 
                        $this->db->where('key',$key);    
                        $this->db->insert('users',$userdata);

                        }   



            $this->load->model('more_m');

            $this->db->set('status', "'approved'",FALSE);
            $this->db->where('id',$id);
            $this->db->update('user_request');


            //die();
            redirect('admin/new_user');

      }
```

The query just fetched one key so inserted only that key instead of fetching all the keys it was a silly mistake i did not took notice off.

Answer (score 0):

In your example the script execution is stopped using:

```
echo $this->db->last_query(); die();
```

after first insert the second query won't execute.

Also you can debug what return the "$request" variable - var_dump($request); After that you will know how many loops are

Comment: that i have stoppped just for debugging purpose. I just wanted to know what actual query is genrated

Comment: Also if i remove that i wont make a difference as the script only inserts users it does not know to insert user for which reseller :(

Comment: Can you add a structure of users db table?

Comment: Yes Updated the question please check

Comment: Please add also Indexes of this tables, It is important to know if there are some unique keys

Comment: Again updated  Please check. the id is primary key and auto incremented. and the field called key in both users and reseller in genrated through code i mean i generate a unique string and store it in key field

Comment: As mentioned in question each users is mapped to it reseller by that unique field called key which is generated through a code

Comment: debugging i have already removed from code thanks for that :) but m concerned about how to insert users for that reseller whose button is clicked to yes  and not only the first reseller

Comment: just add echo $this->db->last_query(); in loop and add die() after loop - then you will see all queries and will execute inside phpMyadmin - then will know what is the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91357/discussion-between-pavel-and-rajan).

Comment: i know the problem as mentioned the query genrated is :INSERT INTO `users` (`key`) VALUES ('Rajan-92-1-100-1') but i want to do something like this insert into users table key ="something" where id="resellerid" but i dont think insert has where statment so dont know how to achieve my requirement

Comment: and by generating users i mean that a blank row would be created in users table with only one field filled that would be the key and the reseller key will be inserted there
This is very confusing of-course
but i hope u understood what i want